# Backup SQL Schema Only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, backup

I need to create a backup of a SQL Server 2005 Database that's only the structure...no records, just the schema. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: I'm trying to create a backup file to use with old processes, so a script wouldn't work for my purposes, sorry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a 3 step process:

1. Generate a script from the working database
2. Create a new database from that script
3. Create a backup of the new database

Comment: And now, depending on SSMS settings: indices gone, foreign keys gone, check constrains gone, triggers gone, full text indices gone, datacompression gone, unique constraints gone, PRIMARY KEYS gone. Dependency order wrong. Encrypted objects missing. Object depending on Linked servers cannot be created. Objects depending on those objects that were not created cannot be created... and so on... Oh well, looks like a schema backup, but it really isn't one.

Comment: Sadly, even with SSMS 2016 nothing was fixed from what Stefan mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use SQL Management Studio to create a complete script of your database and the objects?

Comment: Because it doesn't get the dependencies right, it's missing encrypted objects (everything might be encrypted), and can't create an object if it's missing for example a linked server in another environment...

Answer (score 0):

I make heavy use of this tool:
[SQLBalance for MySQL](http://www.dswsoft.com/sqlbalance.php)

Unfortunately; its windows only... but works like a charm to move databases around, data or no data, merge or compare.

Answer (score 0):

Toad for SQL Server does this nicely, if you're considering a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2012 (patched), you can make a schema only clone of your database using [DBCC CLONEDATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql). Then simply backup the clone.

```
dbcc clonedatabase(Demo, Demo_Clone) with verify_clonedb;
alter database [Demo_Clone] set read_write;
backup database [Demo_Clone] to disk = N'C:\temp\Demo_SchemaOnly_20220821.bak';
drop database [Demo_Clone];
```

Read more here: [Schema Only Database Backup](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/schema-only-database-backup)