# backup SQL Server 2005 database without data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

I have one stored procedure to backup the database. It will backup metadata as well as data.

Is there any option to back up the database with out data. ie, back up only the schema (Empty tables).

I don't want to script the database.

Comment: You could run TRUNCATE TABLE statements for each table prior to running your backup sproc, assuming you don't care about/need the currently existing data at all.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589/backup-sql-schema-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution already on StackOverflow - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589/backup-sql-schema-only).

Comment: he doesn't want to script the database though, but neverthless simple solution :)

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga
But this solution can be scripted as well. If not, that'll be awful as a daily task :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `SQL SERVER SCRIPT WIZARD`