# how to take sql database backup without data

Tags: sql-server, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup SQL Schema Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589/backup-sql-schema-only)

Anybody tell how to take sql database backup without data. i wanted to take all the tables and structures from sql server 2008. and import to another sql server 2008. i dont need the data.

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589/backup-sql-schema-only

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use "tasks" -> "Generate scripts" and choose what you want to script. Run, save to a file, open the file against the new database and run the script after changing the database name to match (if it changed)

Comment: I can't ! Every view, stored procedure and function is encrypted ! :(

Comment: If you can't view that means you probably shouldn't view. This is a question for your DBA.

Comment: I am the developer. We have backups. It'd just be intended to backup the code. Data isn't changed.

Comment: @Otávio Décio: And even if the objects wouldnt be encrypted, now, depending on SSMS settings: indices gone, foreign keys gone, check constrains gone, triggers gone, full text indices gone, datacompression gone, unique constraints gone, PRIMARY KEYS gone. Dependency order wrong. Encrypted objects missing. Object depending on Linked servers cannot be created. Objects depending on those objects that were not created cannot be created... and so on... Oh well, looks like a schema backup, but it really isn't one in practise.

Comment: @StefanSteiger - I am open to suggestions.

Comment: It's missing the indexes. Is there any way to bring those along?

Answer (score 6):

First time you can use the script database option, as Otavio suggested.

Subsequent times you can use a tool like [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) or the [Compare Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx) functionality of Visual Studio Database Edition. These tools allow you to synch schema (ie. 'table structure') from one database to another.

Comment: Remus, you can use SQL Compare the first time just as well. Create an empty database, compare it against yours, maybe play with settings to have the script less verbose (no transactions)

Comment: Sure you can, is just a problem of cost since neither RedGate's tool nor VSTS DB are free.

Comment: Dear Thanks for your suggetions

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making scripts.
The way to go is:

- Right click the table you want to script to the other database.
- Script table as: -> Create to New query window.

Comment: dear Younes. thanks. but I have more 300 tables and many procedured s and functions.

Comment: I guess the answer above me suites you best then hehe.