# Backup SQL Server Schema With Data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

I've been tasked with creating a backup of the data in our "default schema" database **dbo** to the same database using a new schema called **dbobackup**.

I honestly do not understand what this means as far as a database goes. Apparently, it is like having a database backup inside the existing database. I guess there is some advantage to doing that.

Anyway, I can't seem to find anywhere online that will allow me to do this.

I have found a few posts on here about copying the schema without data, but I need the data too.

[Backup SQL Schema Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3589/153923)

How do I check to see if a schema exists, delete it if it does, and then create a schema that accepts data in the current database?

Once I have the new schema created, can I dump data in there with a simple command like this?

```
SELECT * INTO [dbobackup].Table1 FROM [dbo].Table1;
```

That line only backs up one table, though. If I need to do this to 245 tables for this particular customer, I'd need a script.

We have several customers, too, and their databases are not structured identically.

Could I do something along these lines?

I was thinking about creating a small console program to walk through the tables.

How would I modify something like the code below to do what I want?

```
public static void Backup(string sqlConnection)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var tables = new List<String>();
        var sqlSelectTables = "SELECT TableName FROM [dbo];";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectTables, conn))
        {
            using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    var item = String.Format("{0}", r["TableName"]).Trim();
                    tables.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        var fmtSelectInto = "SELECT * INTO [dbobackup].{0} FROM [dbo].{0}; ";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(null, conn))
        {
            foreach (var item in tables)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(fmtSelectInto, item);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking there's got to be a tool that would do that; have you czeched out Database Toolbox? It's the cat's meow when it comes to working with SQL databases. See http://www.upscene.com/ Note: I am not affiliated with Upscene, just a very impressed customer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server already has this built in.  If you open SQL Server Management Studio and right click on the database you want to back up, then select all tasks then backup, you will get an option to back up your database into an existing database.

This is the important part and why you should use the built in functionality: You must copy the data from one DB to the other DB *in the correct order* or you'll get foreign key errors all over the place.  If you have a lot of data tables with a lot of relationships, this will really be hard to nail down on your own.  You could write code to make a complete graph of all of the dependencies and then figure out what order to copy the table data (which is essentially what SQL Server already does).

Additionally, there are third-party programs available to do this type of backup as well (see: Google).

Comment: I'm not a great DBA, and I have only done a handful of backups. Could you go into detail about how to do this? Maybe add in a few screenshots for bullet points that may not be clear? I would certainly appreciate it. This might be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a "work in progress" approach I got started with that looks promising:

```
public static void CopyTable(
  string databaseName,   // i.e. Northwind
  string tableName,      // i.e. Employees
  string schema1,        // i.e. dbo
  string schema2,        // i.e. dboarchive
  SqlConnection sqlConn)
{
    var conn = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConn);
    var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(conn);
    var db = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database(server, databaseName);
    db.Tables.Refresh();
    for (var itemId = 0; itemId < db.Tables.Count; itemId++)
    {
        var table = db.Tables.ItemById(itemId);
        if (table.Name == tableName)
        {
            table.Schema = String.Format("{0}", DatabaseSchema.dboarchive);
            table.Create();
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue I am currently running into is that my **db** variable always comes back with **Tables.Count == 0**.

If I get a chance to fix this, I will update.

For now, I've been told to remove this piece of code and check my code in.